# Angular Service Worker giving 504 (Gateway Timeout ) Error on reload

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have started to implement service worker to my application. It is registered properly , but when I refresh the page it is giving  **net::ERR_ABORTED 504 (Gateway Timeout)** error. But when I tick the Update on reload property in chrome dev tools where we can see the service worker registered or not, it works fine.

Can anyone let me know what I am missing, because we cannot have control on user's machine to tick that property. What I can do right to reload and all the caching files reloads properly.

[image]